# AppCenter React Native Android build failed Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)

Tags: android, react-native

> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
> Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
> > Connection reset

> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: We have been seeing similar failures the last few days. We can access the files from our local network, so possibly something specific to AppCenter and their network.

Comment: Yes, it can be. because I am able to build from Android studio locally, but the App center build is failing. Don't know how can it be fixed

Comment: Same as the other commenters. Not sure what the problem is yet.

Comment: Same problem here. Only one build out of last 10 worked on android...

Comment: Yes, it's very rare like 1/15 build gets completed successfully, but it takes huge time as every build takes around 20 mins to build or fail.

Comment: Same problem in a React native project. Did you get any response from AppCenter ?

Comment: Not till now. Still waiting @gusgard

Comment: It seems `jcenter` is deprecated and it might be related to that. More information https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown#check

Comment: I removed jcenter and add mavenCentral in Gradle.. but still no success. @gusgard

Comment: @all please check the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have `enableAapt2` in my project but I added with the `true` value and it didn't work

Comment: Any news on what Appcenter told you? @Sangeeta

Comment: No Actually I got a solution that worked for me @PaulIvanov.. please see the answer

Comment: This is 100% app center's networking issue.

Comment: Did you get any updates from AppCenter? @JuanCarlos try removing jcenter and add mavenCentral in gradle as it may resolve your issue. or try resequencing google and jcenter also worked in some cases

Comment: Did not work @Sangeeta I tried several combinations(locally), and nothing. I retried several times and it build. And it now builds without an issue, so it is 100% AppCenter's fault.

Comment: Which gradle version you are using? @JuanCarlos

Comment: @Sangeeta I"m using 3.5.2. But I cannot change it, if I do it breaks. App is not mine, I'm just configuring pipelines.

Comment: I thought it was related to jcenter depreciation so I forced groovy to be downloaded not from jcenter with `excludeGroupByRegex "org\\.codehaus\\.groovy.*"`.
And now I have the same error but failing to download from the maven2 repo...
`Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.`

So it's not a jcenter issue, atleast that's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find an answer, I am sharing it here because if anyone found the same issue can fix it.

Please remove **android.enableAapt2=false** from the **Gradle.properties** file. As App center must be using updated Gradle where the Aapt tool is true by default, this line is deprecated So remove it and try building the app on App center again.

I hope it will resolve the issue for everyone facing it. :)

Comment: I don't have enableAapt2 in my graddle.propperties :(

Comment: @JuanCarlos which gradle version you are using?

Comment: @JuanCarlos I started getting messages on AppCenter saying: Gradle Task failures may be related to JFrog Bintray Shutdown/Brownouts - https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Comment: Check if it can help @JuanCarlos

Comment: It all works perfectly and we did zero changes to the app. So, as I suspected, it was 100% appcenter's fault.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me with React Native 0.63 and Flipper version 0.54.

I did this to fix it:

1. Download `groovy-all-2.4.15.jar` from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/
2. Create the folder `android/libs` (if you don't have it)
3. Place the `.jar` file in the folder `android/libs` (you should check in the .jar file into your repository)
4. In your root `build.gradle`, add `flatDir`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        // ...
+        flatDir {
+            dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/libs"
+        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I fixed was by adding `mavenCentral()` before `jcenter`. I didn't need to do it in all the node_modules. Just in the `build.gradle` of the app

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because in the free tier allows only 30mins of build time and if it exceeds the connection is reset and the build fails.

[image: Appcenter tiers]

UPDATE:- Seems Jcenter is not maintained anymore.So will have to switch to mavenCentral as an alternative.

For more info :-

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/jcentershut
- https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Comment: Not always. In my case build duration is around ~12 mins. This is mostly because [JCenter is down](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown).

Comment: @PasinduDilshan Yess seems that is the issue :)